# Automatic fitting of text content to page with rst2pdf

Tags: pdf, layout, font-size, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

Does rst2pdf provide automatic adjustment of text size to fit a bullet or numbered list to the page for presentation purposes? Similar to what LaTeX provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have size-to-fit. I use rst2pdf for presentations and I use a consistent font size throughout my slide decks, and I quite like the effect it produces. (Sorry this is probably not the answer you were hoping for!)